# How to implement listview by using aspx

Tags: c#, mysql

How to display MySql database table datas by using aspx,Iam using visual studio express for web 2013,so i want to display my mysql table in inline by using aspx,so i dont know how to implement this by using listview.I can get entire table by using a datatable,so now i want to implement it in aspx page Here is my aspx.cs file.

```
 public partial class mydata : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetAllfilmperson();
    }
    public static DataTable GetAllfilmperson()
    {
        try
        {
            string connString = "Server=localhost;database=contentupload;uid=root;password=Mangal$1";
            string query = "SELECT * FROM `contentupload`.`film_person`";
            // string query = "SELECT CONCAT(person_first_name, ', ', person_last_name) as FullName from contentupload`.`film_person";
            MySqlDataAdapter ma = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connString);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            ma.Fill(DS);
            return DS.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            return GetAllfilmperson();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful, if you get a MySqlException then you call the method perhaps in an endless loop.

Comment: What do mean by "implement". Are you trying to display the data?

Comment: @Icemanind  yes...absolutely, and also i want to edit,update and delete...

Comment: @UnnikrishnanS - Is this WebForms or MVC?

Comment: So you are loading the page and calling your `GetAllfilmperson` method. And if you don't get the results you expect, your `catch` calls the function again. And if you don't get the results you expent, your `catch` calls the function again. This is insanity!!!! Same action, expecting different results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show the data, place a ListView (or a similar control) on your page either by using the designer or adding the appropriate tags. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790(v=vs.100).aspx) for an extended description of the ListView control and how to use it.
The markup should look similar to this:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" >
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <table runat="server" id="table1" >
      <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" ></tr>
    </table>
  </LayoutTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr runat="server">
      <td runat="server">
        <%-- Data-bound content. --%>
        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" 
          Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) for details on the control.

In order to bind the data, you should set the `DataSource` property of the control and call the `DataBind` method afterwards:

```
 public partial class mydata : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var tbl = GetAllfilmperson();
            ListView1.DataSource = tbl;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    // ...

}
```